# Is there a way to count the number of times a constexpr function has been called?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I have a class template and a function template that look like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct IdGenerator
{
    static unsigned int s_idCount_;
    template<typename U>
    static int newID()
    {
        static const unsigned int id = s_idCount_++;
        return id;
    };
};
template<typename T> unsigned int IdGenerator<T>::s_idCount_ = 1;
```

As you can see, it allows me to get an id for every combination of two types:

```
IdGenerator<int>::newID<float>() // 1
IdGenerator<int>::newID<char>() // 2
IdGenerator<float>::newID<int>() // 1
...
```

What I'm trying to do but can't seem to wrap my head around is making this entire thing work at compile-time. It looks to me like all of this could be evaluated at compile-time since we all we're doing is counting template instantiations, which is a compile-time occurrence.
But at the same time, I have no idea how one would increment the id count at compile-time.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, if not with this specific layout then with some other design?

Comment: There are some arcane tricks that make it possible, but they're prone to breaking when you change (or update!) your compiler. And they don't work across TU boundaries, while your approach does. The only thing I'd change is to move `s_idCount_` to a function, which will allow it to be used before entering `main`.

Comment: Clearly not possible in general: Changing the first line to `if (runtime_condition) IdGenerator<int>::newID<float>();` causes the ID assignments to change at runtime, which cannot be determined at compile time.